# Onsen - pushPage animation

Tags: onsen-ui

I have a multiline toolbar. The code is like:

```
<ons-page id="prodotti">

<ons-toolbar fixed-style id="firstNav" class="first-line">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="dist/img/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="myNav.pushPage('profilo.html')">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-person" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="myNav.pushPage('carrello.html')">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-android-cart" size="28px" fixed-width="false"><span class="notification">1</span></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>

    <div class="second-line navigation-bar" id="secondNav">
        <div class="navigation-bar__left">
            <span class="toolbar-button navigation-bar__line-height" onclick="menu.toggle()">
                <i class="ion-navicon"
            style="font-size:28px; vertical-align:-6px;"></i>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

All my page have a toolbar like this one.
Now I have a problem. When I use pushPage with animation:slide the #secondNav doesn't seems to have animation. It will change after the end of the animation.
How I can implement the slide to this element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code. `ons-toolbar` accepts only `div` tags with class= left, center or right.
Your `<div class="second-line navigation-bar" id="secondNav">` will never be displayed. To create a two line toolbar, just use two different toolbars.
In your code the navigator is missing, I added it on the `first` page. You also forgot to add the `</ons-page>` tag in the end.

[Here](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/pJoyVJ) you can find a working CodPen example, and here is your modified code:

```html
<ons-template id="profilo.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-back-button>Go Back</ons-back-button>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>

<ons-page id="first">
  <ons-navigator var="myNav">
    <ons-toolbar fixed-style id="firstNav" class="first-line">
    
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="myNav.pushPage('profilo.html')">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-person" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="myNav.pushPage('carrello.html')">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-android-cart" size="28px" fixed-width="false"><span class="notification">1</span></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    
    <div class="second-line navigation-bar" id="secondNav">
        <div class="navigation-bar__left">
            <span class="toolbar-button navigation-bar__line-height" onclick="menu.toggle()">
                <i class="ion-navicon"
            style="font-size:28px; vertical-align:-6px;"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ons-navigator>
 </ons-page>
```

Comment: Thank you @AndiPavllo. My code have some missing items because it is only a little block.
Even if your code seems to do the work, it doesn't. 
I try to explain. The second toolbar must be fixed like the first. I have tried your code before mine, but if I add the css position:fixed, it will work fine only in codepen, but not on my mobile phone or in FF and this is a big problem. This is the reason why I put the secondNav in the first toolbar with a little help of javascript. I see the second toolbar, but its behaviour isn't right.
Have you any hint to fix the second toolbar with your code?

Comment: @fraymas can you please provide your testing platform and the build number?